# how can i include my array property into class constructor and be able to access it via object initialization?

Tags: c#, oop

i'm very new to programming and in the progress of learning.
here is my code

```
namespace ConsoleApp9
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Person p = new Person("john", "doe", tittles:null);
            Person td = new Person("tom","jones");
            Person w = new Person();
            Console.WriteLine(td);
            Console.WriteLine(p.SayHello("vahid"));
            var str = p.SayHello("nick");
            Console.WriteLine(str);
            p.DoSome();
            var m = w.Tittles[0];
            Console.WriteLine(m);



        }
    }
    public class Person
    {

        public string FirstName { get; private set; }
        public string LastName { get; private set; }
        private string[] tittles = new string[6] {
            "Mr","Mrs", "Miss","Sir", "Doctor","Sister"
        };
        public string[] Tittles
        {
            get { return tittles; }
            set { tittles = value; }
        }

        public Person()
        {

        }
        public Person(string firstName, string lastName)
        {
            FirstName = firstName;
            LastName = lastName;
        }
        public Person(string firstName, string lastName, string[] tittles  )
        {
            FirstName = firstName;
            LastName = lastName;
            Tittles = tittles;

        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "Welcome to C# " + Tittles[0] + " " + FirstName + " " + LastName;
        }
        public string SayHello(string name)
        {
            return "hello " + name;
        }
        public void DoSome()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(FirstName + " "+ LastName + " this is a void method.");
        }

    }
}
```

my question is how to give other value than null in Person p = new Person("john", "doe", tittles:null);
tittles is my string array
i tried tittles[1] forexample but end up with an error.
is there a way this could be done?
thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to do it:

```
Person p = new Person("john", "doe", new string[] { "one", "two" });
```

Or, you could use the `params` keyword to define a constructor that takes any number of strings:

```
        public Person(string firstName, string lastName, params string[] tittles)
        {
            FirstName = firstName;
            LastName = lastName;
            Tittles = tittles;
        }
```

Then you can create Person objects with any number of titles without having to create a temporary string array:

```
Person p = new Person("john", "doe", "one", "two");
Person j = new Person("jane", "doe", "one", "two", "three");
Person td = new Person("tom", "jones", "mr");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are instantiating your class with the constructor that take 3 arguments you will override the private field array `titles` in your class. I am assuming that you want to keep the values in there and therefore you should instantiate the class with the constructor that takes 2 arguments as that does not touch the Titles property

```
Person p = new Person("John", "Doe");
```

When instantiating with 3 args provide an array of strings like this:

```
Person p = new Person ("John", "Doe", new string[]{"title1", "title2"})
```